# SHA256 hashes for newest AEON release

Tags: aeon, hash-verification

Where can I find the SHA256 hashes for [AEON v.0.9.11](https://github.com/aeonix/aeon/releases/tag/v0.9.11.0)? Preferably I would like to see the hashes GPG signed by an AEON developer and is the norm for [Monero releases](https://getmonero.org/downloads/hashes.txt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the momnent, they don't exist. This is likely to change as the currency gains traction. You can always go on IRC Freenode #aeon and ask the devs to add some hashes.

Comment: Of course, you could simply build Aeon yourself from source. No SHA256 needed after that :)